# how to detect for json values that "don't exist" for a discord.py bot

Tags: python, json, discord.py

```
def sav():
    with open('values.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(values, outfile)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} is now online')


@client.command()
async def cb(ctx):
    if not values[ctx.author.id]["created_account"]:
        values[ctx.author.id] = {"money": 100, "premium": False, "created_account": True}
        sav()
        await ctx.send('you made a bal')
    if values[ctx.author.id]["created_account"]:
        await ctx.send("you already have an account")
```

how can I possibly detect if they have already made an account if they don't even have a `"created_account" = False` value in the values.json file

Answer (score 1):

The `created_account` key doesn't make sense at all, there won't be any info about the user in the dictionary if it's not created. You can do what stijndcl suggested or you can use `dict.get` and set a default value.

```py
accounts = {'acc1': {"money": 100, "premium": False, "created_account": True}, 'acc2': {"money": 10, "premium": False, "created_account": True}}
user_to_get = 'acc3'
                       # The key to get, the default value
account = accounts.get(user_to_get, None)

if account is None:
    # account does not exists
else:
    # account does exists
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is

```py
if "created_account" not in values[ctx.author.id]
```